# I cant set filename to a generated zip file from remote files and is too slow

Tags: php, html, zip, simple-html-dom, file-management

I have created a website which allows the user to `zip` multiple files from remote sites, combine them into a `zip` file, then download them. This part is working very well.

**The problems I am having:**

1) The `zip` takes too long to generate when combining multiple files

2) I cannot set the `zip` files name to be `$name`

This is what I have:

```
<?php

$files = unserialize($_POST['filesend']);
$name = $_POST['name'];

$zip = new ZipArchive();

$tmp_file = tempnam('.','');
$zip->open($tmp_file, ZipArchive::CREATE);

foreach($files as $file){
  $download_file = file_get_contents($file);
  $zip->addFromString(basename($file),$download_file);
}

$zip->close();

function downloadfile ($file, $contenttype = 'application/octet-stream') {
    @error_reporting(0);

    if (!file_exists($file)) {
        header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
        exit;
    }

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) $range = $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']; 
    else if ($apache = apache_request_headers()) { 
        $headers = array();
        foreach ($apache as $header => $val) $headers[strtolower($header)] = $val;
  if (isset($headers['range'])) $range = $headers['range'];
  else $range = FALSE; 
} else $range = FALSE; 

$filesize = filesize($file);
if ($range) {
  $partial = true;
  list($param,$range) = explode('=',$range);
  if (strtolower(trim($param)) != 'bytes') { 
    header("HTTP/1.1 400 Invalid Request");
    exit;
  }
  $range = explode(',',$range);
  $range = explode('-',$range[0]); 
  if (count($range) != 2) { 
    header("HTTP/1.1 400 Invalid Request");
    exit;
  }
  if ($range[0] === '') { 
    $end = $filesize - 1;
    $start = $end - intval($range[0]);
  } else if ($range[1] === '') { 
    $start = intval($range[0]);
    $end = $filesize - 1;
  } else { 
    $start = intval($range[0]);
    $end = intval($range[1]);
    if ($end >= $filesize || (!$start && (!$end || $end == ($filesize - 1)))) $partial = false; 
  }      
  $length = $end - $start + 1;
} else $partial = false;

header("Content-Type: $contenttype");
header("Content-Length: $filesize");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename= $name .zip");
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

if ($partial) {
  header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content'); 
  header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$filesize"); 
  if (!$fp = fopen($file, 'r')) { 
    header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");
    exit;
  }
  if ($start) fseek($fp,$start);
  while ($length) { 
    $read = ($length > 8192) ? 8192 : $length;
    $length -= $read;
    print(fread($fp,$read));
  }
  fclose($fp);
} else readfile($file); 

exit;

}
downloadfile ($tmp_file, $contenttype = 'application/octet-stream');
?>
```

**Sample input:**

```
$files = array("http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20100520131746/logopedia/images/5/5c/Google_logo.png","http://www.logobird.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/new-google-chrome-logo.jpg","http://steve-lovelace.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/google-logo-in-chicago-font.png","http://fc08.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2013/111/d/6/applejack_google_logo__install_guide___by_thepatrollpl-d62gui3.png","http://www.sfweekly.com/binary/fb4a/go.jpg","https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2014/world-cup-2014-16-5975619640754176.3-hp.gif");
$name = "Google Logo's 33";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address your two issues:

**1) Slow file processing speed.**
I don't know that you can help that. It is what it is.

**2) Saving the name.**
I have formatted this into a class, just to keep jobs separate. I find a class works better in a situation like this because it's easier to read. That being said, because each method may use the protected `$filename` you should copy everything here instead of breaking this code out an mixing your procedural with this class:

```
class   DownloadFiles
    {
        protected   $filename;
        protected   $Zipper;

        public  function Initialize($filename = false)
            {
                // Set the file name in the construct
                $this->filename =   ($filename != false)? $filename:"file".date("YmdHis");

                // New ZipArchive instance
                $this->Zipper   =   new ZipArchive();   
                // Drop the filename here
                $this->Zipper->open($this->filename, ZipArchive::CREATE);
                // Return the method for optional chaining.
                return $this;
            }

        public  function AddFiles($array = array())
            {
                if(!isset($this->Zipper))
                    return $this;

                // This is just if you wanted to also use a string
                // separated by commas, it will convert to array
                if(!is_array($array) && strpos($array,",") !== false)
                    $array  =   explode(",",$array);

                // Loop through files (as you have it already)
                if(is_array($array) && !empty($array)) {
                        foreach($array as $url) {
                                    // Add Contents (as you have it)                                
                                    $this->Zipper->addFromString(basename($url),file_get_contents($url));
                            }
                    }
                // Close zip file
                $this->Zipper->close();
                // Return for method chaining
                return $this;
            }

        public  function DownloadZip($contenttype = 'application/octet-stream')
            {
                if(!isset($this->filename))
                    return $this;

                // Nothing really changes in this function except
                // you don't need the name as an option in this function
                error_reporting(0);
                if (!file_exists($this->filename)) {
                        header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
                        exit;
                    }

                $range  =   false; 

                if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
                    $range = $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']; 
                elseif($apache = apache_request_headers()) { 
                        $headers = array();

                        foreach ($apache as $header => $val)
                            $headers[strtolower($header)] = $val;

                        $range = (isset($headers['range']))? $headers['range']:false;
                    }

                $filesize   =   filesize($this->filename);
                $partial    =   false;

                if($range) {
                        $partial = true;
                        list($param,$range) = explode('=',$range);

                        if(strtolower(trim($param)) != 'bytes') { 
                                header("HTTP/1.1 400 Invalid Request");
                                exit;
                            }

                        $range  =   explode(',',$range);
                        $range  =   explode('-',$range[0]); 

                        if(count($range) != 2) { 
                                header("HTTP/1.1 400 Invalid Request");
                                exit;
                            }

                        if($range[0] === '') { 
                                $end    =   $filesize - 1;
                                $start  =   $end - intval($range[0]);
                            }
                        elseif($range[1] === '') { 
                                $start  =   intval($range[0]);
                                $end    =   $filesize - 1;
                            }
                        else { 
                                $start  =   intval($range[0]);
                                $end    =   intval($range[1]);

                                if($end >= $filesize || (!$start && (!$end || $end == ($filesize - 1))))
                                    $partial = false; 
                            }      
                                $length = $end - $start + 1;
                    }

                header("Content-Type: $contenttype");
                header("Content-Length: $filesize");
                header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$this->filename.'.zip');
                header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

                if($partial) {
                        header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content'); 
                        header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$filesize"); 

                        if(!$fp = fopen($this->filename, 'r')) { 
                                header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");
                                exit;
                            }

                        if($start)
                            fseek($fp,$start);

                        while($length) { 
                                $read   =   ($length > 8192) ? 8192 : $length;
                                $length -= $read;
                                print(fread($fp,$read));
                            }

                        fclose($fp);
                    }
                else
                    readfile($this->filename); 

                exit;
            }
    }
?>
```

**To use:**

```
$files[] = "http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20100520131746/logopedia/images/5/5c/Google_logo.png";
$files[] = "http://www.logobird.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/new-google-chrome-logo.jpg";
$files[] = "http://steve-lovelace.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/google-logo-in-chicago-font.png";
$files[] = "http://fc08.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2013/111/d/6/applejack_google_logo__install_guide___by_thepatrollpl-d62gui3.png";
$files[] = "http://www.sfweekly.com/binary/fb4a/go.jpg";
$files[] = "https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2014/world-cup-2014-16-5975619640754176.3-hp.gif";

$name    = "Google Logo's 33";
// Initialize
$ZDownload  =   new DownloadFiles();
// Run downloader
$ZDownload->Initialize($name)->AddFiles($files)->DownloadZip();
```

Comment: Yeah I don't know because the file(s) have to be downloaded first which is dependent on the speed of the connection to and from the server, so I don't know how much you can affect that. I tried the code a series of times and it had different speeds, some slower some faster.

Comment: is it possible by getting the header ??

Comment: or can i show a progress bar while the zip is generated